# How come my catch block is not executing?

Tags: async-await, promise, try-catch

How come my catch block is not being executed when login gives an error? This is my event handler:

```
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await login(dispatch, loginUser);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setSnackbarOpen(true);
      setErrorMessage(err.response.data.message);
    }
  };
```

And this is my login action:

```
export const login = async (dispatch, payload) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "USER_REQUEST",
    });

    const res = await axios.post("/api/users/auth/signin", payload);

    dispatch({
      type: "SET_USER",
      payload: {
        user: {
          email: res.data.email,
          name: res.data.name,
        },
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("CAUGHT ERROR IN login()");
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_ERROR",
      payload: { error: err.response.data.message },
    });
    return err;
  }
};
```

I get the "CAUGHT ERROR IN login()" logged but the code in my handleLogin catch block isn't executed.

Comment: Your `login()` function NEVER rejects the promise it returns so therefore `await login()` will never go to the `catch`.  The `login()` function sometimes does `return err`, but that's just a value being returned, not a rejected promise.  If you want the promise that `login()` returns to be rejected, then you must `throw err` instead of `return err` in `login()` from within your `catch()` block.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This was really good info and it solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `login()` function NEVER rejects the promise it returns so therefore `await login()` will never go to the catch. The `login()` function sometimes does `return err`, but that's just a value being returned, not a rejected promise. If you want the promise that `login()` returns to be rejected, then you must `throw err` instead of `return err` in `login()` from within your `catch()` block.

```
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("CAUGHT ERROR IN login()");
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_ERROR",
      payload: { error: err.response.data.message },
    });
    throw err;     // <== this changed to throw instead of return
  }
```